# Constructor is ignoring "for" loop(Java)

Tags: java

So I feel kind of stupid, because it looks like I'm missing something trivial and I've used loops before, but now we're at the stage in our class where we're using them a lot and I can't seem to find the problem after trying many different combinations, so here goes :

```
public class BusStop
{
  private BusArrival[] _buses;
  private int _noOfBuses;
  final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;

  //================================ CONSTRUCTORS ============================//

 public BusStop(int size){       // THIS 
  _buses = new BusArrival[size]; // IS
                                 // THE 
     for(int i=0; i< size; i++){ // PROBLEMATIC
       if(_buses[i] != null){    // LOOP
          _noOfBuses ++;
        }         
      } 
  }
  //=============================== METHODS =================================//

  public int  getNoOfBuses(){
      return _noOfBuses;
    }

public boolean add (int line, int pass, Time1 t){ // adds a BussArrival object to an empty array (if there's any).
    for (int i=0; i < _buses.length; i++){
        if(_buses[i] == null){
            _buses[i] = new BusArrival(line, pass, t);
            return true;
        }           
    }

      return false;    
}
```

Here's a constructor of the BusArrival class, just so you have a general idea :

```
public BusArrival(int lineNum, int pass, Time1 t){

    _lineNumber = lineNum;
    _noOfPassengers = pass;
    _arrivalTime = t;

}
```

And here's Time1 constructor from a saparate class, just for this to make sense :

```
public Time1(int h, int m, int s)

    _hour = h;
    _minute = m;
    _second = s;

}
```

Here's my main method :

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main (String [] args){
      BusStop first = new BusStop(4);
      Time1 one = new Time1(10,30,0);
      Time1 two = new Time1(10,0,0);
      first.add(1,2,one);
      first.add(2,3,two);
      System.out.println(first.getNoOfBuses());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the output is "0" when I do that.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The initializing loop looks fine to me. It shouldn't run since your array is all null. Actually, you just created a new array. Why are you checking if the elements are null immediately? Of course they are! :)

Comment: You're declaring a new array of objects, and by default every object in that array will be null until you initialize it.  Then you loop through the array and check for nulls, which of course they all are.  So that loop is working fine, but your `if` statement in that loop will always be `false`.  It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish in that constructor.

Comment: I've added 2 objects of the type "BusArrival" to 2 empty arrays (out of 4), so when I'm trying to print the number of buses (first.getNoOfBuses()), it should count only the the arrays that have a "BusArrival" object stored in them, if not, it should ignore.

Comment: Yes, but in my main method I've added 2 objects to 2 empty arrays, by using them "add" method (public boolean add).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the problem.

Number of buses is only assigned in the initializer, but in the initializer you aren't adding any buses. Hence you get 0 buses.

When you add a bus, you are not updating number of buses. So you get 0.

You should do `_noOfBuses++;` when you successfully added a bus. Also, take out that loop in the initializer. When you initialized an array all the entries are null, so the loop is useless :)

Edit:
You seem to be confused about the order of execution of your code.

In your `main` function, you are first initializing a `BusStop`. This means he initializer code is ran (which includes the loop in your initializer).

Then you added the two buses. However, note that the loop is already executed, it won't be executed again, because the initializer is only run once.

Therefore, your loop is never going to increment `_noOfBuses`

Comment: Yep, I'm an idiot, thank you!! I added the loop to the "getNoOfBuses" method and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the number of busses every time that you add a new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
public BusStop(int size){       // THIS 
 _buses = new BusArrival[size]; // IS
                                // THE 
 for(int i=0; i< size; i++){ // PROBLEMATIC
   if(_buses[i] != null){    // LOOP
      _noOfBuses ++;
    }         
  } 
 }
```

In the above code the array `_buses` just gets created with all the items pointing to null. In your for-loop you are using if statement to check if there is any non-null value (which in this case does not exist because there are no items in the array). so your `_noOfBuses ++;` is not reachable.

Comment: But I'm adding 2 BusArrival objects in my main method to 2 empty arrays

Answer (score 0):

**First** Add another constructor with no arguments to your BusArrival class. Just like this.

```
  public BusArrival() {}
```

**Second** Modify the BusStop constructor to the following

```
public BusStop(int size){ 
_buses = new BusArrival[size];
 for(int i=0; i<_buses.length; i++)  {
   _buses[i] = new BusArrival();
   _noOfBuses ++;
 }                         
}
```